# How to properly terminate a Cat6 cable?

Tags: home-networking, cable

I've been trying to terminate my home network Ethernet cables according to [spec](http://www.groundcontrol.com/galileo/ch5-ethernet.htm). I've been having many problems:

- Wires don't reach the end of the connector.
- Wires will bend inside the connector.
- Wires will swap position. You always have to check.
- Crimped connector gets stuck in a closed crimping tool, so now I use an [open one](https://www.allekabels.nl/stekker-doos-en-krimptang/188/1750/modulaire-krimptang-rj45.html).
- According to [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rV5vgk2Mt3I), Cat6 connectors require an adapter to guide the wires, so I got [special connectors](https://www.allekabels.nl/stekker-doos-en-krimptang/188/1077154/cat-6-modulaire-rj45-stekker-tule.html) for this.
- I don't know how to use the third piece (the connected square tubes). The seller says it can be used to separate the higher and lower wires, but how? It should still work without this piece though.
- I use cutters[image: cutters] that should be suited for cutting electrical cords, but especially after separating the wires for the Cat6 connector, I find it very difficult to make them all equally long.
- Even when the Cat6 connector looked okay it never worked.
- Even when the Cat5 connector looked perfect it only allows for very slow internet, like less than 1% of the speed I should have.

Network topology:
Fiber cable from the street > meter cupboard > fiber router installed by the internet provider > 2m network cable > internet router installed by the internet provider (I moved it away but moved it back later) > 30m cable to my room (this cable is causing problems) > switch > 2m cable to my PC.

Network history:

1. A professional technician installed the cable and terminated the ends. It worked well.
2. In order to keep the cable from moving around and prevent people from tripping over it, I used a nail to keep it in place.
3. The nail bend in the cable and damaged it, causing my internet to become unreliable.
4. I cut the cable. Since the extra length was in my room I drew that end to the meter cupboard and crimped a new Cat5 connector on it instead of the Cat6 connector it had. So the cable is now shorter than 30m. My internet now worked fine.
5. In order to have easy access to additional network ports I moved the internet modem to my room. This resulted in an unstable network connection. So eventually I moved the internet modem back to the meter cupboard. And my internet worked fine for a while.
6. I had major troubles attaching the connector at the meter cupboard end. Eventually I managed it with a connector that allows putting the wires through the connector and cutting them off after they come out on the other side. This causes the wires to be somewhat bent and crushed when placed in a socket.
7. After several months of decently working internet it slowed down to an incredibly low speed. I suspected the connector may be faulty so I moved it to another socket. This worked for a while, but it kept failing. Eventually I replaced the entire connector. I couldn't find another such throughput connector, so I just used a normal connector. From then on my internet has been extremely slow.
8. After 4 attempts of attaching a Cat6 connector I ended up using a Cat5 connector, because at least it provides some internet connectivity.
9. After a thorough inspection of the cable I found no damage to it.

What to do?
I could replace the entire cable to ensure it's not damaged.
But since the problem might be that I'm just not able to make good connectors there seems little point to that.
Any tips on how the third component should be used? 
Or specifically on how to attach a Cat6 connector?

Comment: Get a professional cable installer to do it.

Comment: Many problems terminating ethernet cables stem from low quality crimping tools.

Comment: Have you tried connecting the cable directly to your computer and not to the switch to see if it's a bad switch? Is the cable solid or stranded on each color?

Comment: @HazardousGlitch Yes I tried a direct connection. It's a stranded cable, there's a lot of shielding twisted around the wire pairs but the individual wires are very weak.

Comment: @DavidPostill I got a professional cable installer and he couldn't get it working. Apparently he mostly works with CAT5, his collage will come by next week.

Comment: Cat5 and 6 use the same connectors so not sure why the tech  blamed it on the Cat6 unless he was referring to it being stranded as solid is easier to work with. I would replace the entire length. It would probably be cheaper than hiring someone to fix it.

Comment: Cat6 has a cross in the middle of the cable which requires a specialised tool. You can't use a CAT5 tool for these cables with a cross in the middle.